# How do I specify an IPv6 address in the X Window DISPLAY variable?

Tags: xorg, environment-variables, ipv6, x-windows

I'm trying to export a DISPLAY variable containing a numeric IPv6 address. What format would the variable take, since IPv6 addresses contain `:`, which normally is used for the display number? Googling this has come up with a surprising lack of answers.

Comment: Try using the server's hostname instead.  Use `/etc/hosts` if needed.

Comment: Although usable as a workaround for the moment, I do have other boxes on which I do not have root access, and often have autonomous IPv6 negotiated addresses that change frequently. Thus, a non-hacky way to specify the address would be handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put square brackets around the IPv6 address.

```
$ DISPLAY=[::1]:0
```

> [X(7) man page - "DISPLAY NAMES"](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml#heading5)
>
> The hostname part of the display name should be the server machine's
>   hostname or IP address. Full Internet names, abbreviated names, IPv4
>   addresses, and IPv6 addresses are all allowed. For example: x.org:0,
>   expo:0, **[::1]:0**, 198.112.45.11:0, bigmachine:1, and hydra:0.1.